# Netscape LDAPJDK for Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)

Tags: java, pagination, ldap, adlds, netscape

I am using Netscape/Sun LDAP SDK Java library for ADLDS(Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services) as a repository.

I found that AD LDS repository has a limitation of 1000 records for one single database Query transaction using a property called maxPageSize.

How do I override maxPageSize property to query more records (say 5000 records) using the Netscape LDAP SDK java library.

I have googled but nothing found, answeres are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

maxPageSize is a property set on the AD server and there isn't a way to override it from a client SDK.

What you need do is use PagedResultsControl with the LDAP query to fetch records more than maxPageSize.

Refer this link for sample code: https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/SimplePagedResultsControl.html

Comment: I am using the Mozilla(Netscape) Directory java librarary for ADLDS, The one you shared belongs to unbound!!!

Comment: Paging the results is the way to go solve this problem. There should be an equivalent one for Netscape SDK too. Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5618-10/index.html